# Record audio from web page and upload to server

Tags: flash, silverlight, audio-recording

From a web page, I'm looking to record audio from the user's microphone and then upload the file to a server to be stored as an MP3.  My solution is built using .NET.

Most similar apps that I've seen use Flash on the client and presumably Flash Media Server on the server.  We don't have the kind of budget for FMS.  I'm looking for a free/open source solution.

I've also looked a bit at Silverlight 4 since it supports recording WAV audio but I'm not clear on how to tackle the uploading and encoding to MP3 bit.

Ultimately, I need to record audio from the microphone and then be able to store the file on the server as an MP3 file.  Free (or at least cheap) is required.

Any suggestions would be welcome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Back in 2010 when you asked the question tehre was no solution other than using a flash client + media server + ffmpeg to convert from flv to mp3.

But now it's possible thanks to Alchemy/as3.

You should check out the http://audior.ec flash mp3 recording script. I's a small flash script that sits on a webpage and records audio from your visitors/members and saves it as an mp3 on your web server. Red5 or other media server is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free Red5 server instead of Flash Media Server - here is a tutorial how to record audio and video with it: http://mariofalomir.com/blog/?p=101

Comment: Thanks.  However, it looks like this creates an FLV on the server, not MP3.  Is that correct?

Comment: To be honest, I did not look that deeply into what exactly it does on the server, but since the sound in an flv is mp3 format there either might be a way to intercept it before it is getting encoded into an fly or use ffmpeg afterwards to extract the mp3 out of it again.

Answer (score 0):

I was considering using Silverlight as well but for me the problem was I didn't want to require that the user have whatever version of .Net installed.  So I chose ListenUp from Javasonics.com -- and instead am having to rely on a functional Java available to the user's browser, and also am relying on the user to Accept running the applet, when prompted with a popup.  Six of one, half dozen of the other.

Anyways, as far as encoding on the server side I rolled my own python CGI script that converts (in my case, Speex to WAV (using speexdec), and then WAV to MP3 (using lame) and WAV to OGG (using oggenc).  After the fact, I saw http://encoding.com, which has a pay-as-you-go / pre-pay account option.